Flutter: flutter_contacts getContacts no muestra los contactos si estos tienen una etiqueta
Estoy desarrollando en flutter. Intento recuperar los contactos con la librería flutter_contacts . Si me creo contactos en el emulador, los pilla bien, pero cuando desde la aplicación de contactos nativa, añado una etiqueta a un contacto, este desaparece y no me sale más en la lista.
Quería saber si esto es normal o si hay forma de mostrar todos los usuarios indistintivamente de si el contacto tiene etiqueta o no.
Información de mi desarrollo:
Flutter doctor:

Dispositivo emulado, pixel con android 34
Código, función que muestra la lista:
Future<void> _loadContacts() async {
if (await FlutterContacts.requestPermission()) {
  List<Contact> userContacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(withProperties: true, withPhoto: true, withThumbnail: true, withGroups: true, withAccounts: true);
  print("CONTACTOS: $userContacts");
  for (var contact in userContacts) {
    print("Contacto $contact");
    if (contact.organizations.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var org in contact.organizations) {
        print('Contacto: ${contact.displayName}, Organización: ${org.company}');
      }
    }
  }
  List<Group> userGroups = await FlutterContacts.getGroups();
  print("GRUPOs: $userGroups");

} else {
  print("PERMISO DENEGADO");
}

}
Resultado terminal cuando el usuario no pertenece a una etiqueta:

Cuando el usuario pertenece a una etiqueta retorna una lista vacía.
Contactos []
Gracias por leer

Parece un problema extraño con los contactos etiquetados.
